# Variable hidden by if statement, still called on the page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

On my page I have two wrappers some users don't have permission to view the second wrapper so using `@if($user->direct_mail == 0)` I hide the second wrapper which is great!

However when I login into the user I get `Trying to get property of non-object` I think this is because the controller is still passing back the variables for the second wrapper and although its hidden it still throws an error.

Is there a way to not return the variable to the view if it's `null`, or equal to `0`. My understanding was because the content was within the if statement and therefore hidden (which it is) it wouldn't throw an error as the variable isn't called on the page.

Example -

```
@if($user->direct_mail == 0)
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Wrapper 1#</h2>
    {{ $mailJumbo->dm_sent }}
  </div>
@endif
@if($user->website == 0)
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Wrapper 2#</h2>
    {{ $website->stats }}
  </div>
@endif
```

Routes

```
return view('home')
    ->with('website', $website)
    ->with('mailJumbo', $mailJumbo)
```

The variable `$mailJumbo` is null as the user doesn't have the data on his user profile thats why the error exists. If the user has the correct permissions to view both wrappers the error doesn't exist.

Comment: You can add condition to check whether it's null inside `@if`. Not passing variable at all will result in another exception.

Comment: But everything inside the if statement is hidden, which I can check by viewing the page source. So I'm not sure if that would help?

Comment: I would bet that for the type of user that does not have `direct_mail` you have not actually instantiated a class on your `$user` variable. Look back at your controller and how you pass the parameters to this view

Comment: Edit - Your correct if I add the following line - 
`@if ($mailJumbo == '') @else{{ $mailJumbo->dm_sent }}@endif`

The variable is not actioned and the page loads, I just don't understand the logic behind it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that variable is not `null` inside brackets output:

```
{{ ($website) ? $website->stats : null }}
```

Blade engine does not parse it at a runtime, I suppose, that's way you get errors from a block that you think is unreachable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason behind it!

Comment: You're welcome, but googling for it wasn't successful... I'll check it out and get back to the question.

Comment: No, blade won't parse an unreachable block. That means your condition evaluates to true, and the problem is with `User` object.